# Jenkins + Sonar

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I have a project Pensky with two build Jobs on my Jenkins Server. The First Build job does maven build and collects JaCoCo Code coverage report on Post Build Action.

My Second Build Job runs Sonar Analysis on my project. I would like to reuse/feed the JaCoCo code coverage report into my Sonar. But, unable to do so. I see the below message in my build job console

> "Project coverage is set to 0% as build output directory does not
>   exist:"

The sonar job is looking for 'classes' folder in the .sonar directory (in the jenkins job directory).

Can anyone guide me how to feed the report into Sonar. Thank you

This is my sonar.properties

```
    sonar.projectKey=Pensky
    sonar.projectName=Pensky
    sonar.projectVersion=1.1
    sonar.projectDescription= GE Pensky
    sonar.sources=src/main/java
    sonar.tests=src/test/java
    sonar.language=java
    sonar.my.property=value
    sonar.forceAnalysis=true
sonar.jacoco.reportPath=target/jacoco.exec
```

Answer (score 2):

You haven't set the "sonar.binaries" property to point to the build directory (= "target/classes" if you compile it with Maven).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should to copy the folder target of the first job in order to save time. If you do that, you have in the workspace of the job, all the binaries and the jacoco.exec file.

Then, you have to set the folder of the tests result.

*sonar.junit.reportsPath=target/surefire-reports(or other)
sonar.jacoco.ReportPath=target/jacoco.exec*

And finally, you have to set the binaries folder.

*sonar.binaries=target/classes*

Hope I have been helpful.